# Why IF condition is not fulfilled on android

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-studio

I just want to know why the compiler allow to continue the program normally in the first condition:

```
public void ButtonOnClickDirectoryList(View v){
    try {
        if (!spnOptionSelectedDepartment.equals(null) && !spnOptionSelectedCities.equals(null)) {
            if (!spnOptionSelectedTypes.equals(null)) { //code....}
```

the spnOptionSelectedDepartment and spnOptionSelectedTypes are Strings and are defined at the begining of the class like this:

```
private String spnOptionSelectedDepartment = null;
private String spnOptionSelectedCities = null;
private String spnOptionSelectedTypes = null;
```

so when I press the button, it call this method and this are the values that I have in the moment:

```
spnOptionSelectedDepartment = "9999"
spnOptionSelectedCities = null
spnOptionSelectedTypes = null
```

so when I put a break point on this condition it just continue validating the rest of the code inside that if...
Could anybody explain me why this behavior?

Let me edit the question, Yes it throws nullpointer exception on the second if...

```
if (!spnOptionSelectedTypes.equals(null)) {
```

but why it allows the first IF when spnOptionSelectedCities = null...?

Comment: `if (spnOptionSelectedTypes != null)`

Comment: The code posted above will throw a `NullPointerException` if `spnOptionSelectedDepartment` is `null`.

Comment: You should use == to compare a string with null. equals is for comparing values of two strings.

Comment: @yu_sha you are the only one who give a real answer, the rest just mark "not use full" like they think everybody have to know everything...

Comment: @yu_sha I read a lot of how to compare values between strings and it says that the better way to know if a string have known value you sould use String.equal() .....

Comment: @jugger Who told you that? I have some stones waiting to be thrown...

Comment: For specific values, you can `"specific".equals(myStringVariable);` but that never works the other way.

Comment: hmmmmm I get it now, well, When I was studying a Android Course the professor of the course use a lot that and told use that....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't continue, it should throw a `NullPointerException` that you may intercept in the `catch` block.

When you try

```
if (!spnOptionSelectedTypes.equals(null))
```

it should throw this exception because `spnOptionSelectedTypes` is null so it is not a `String` and does not have any `equals()` method.

**Edit:**

It allows the first `if` to pass because it has 2 tests

```
if (A OR B) {
```

If `A` is `true`, the `B` condition is not tested because only one is required to continue, because of the `OR` operator.

**Edit 2:**

With:

if (A AND B) {

If `A` is true, `B` will also be tested and throw a `NullPointerException` if `spnOptionSelectedCities` is null.

**Definitive answer:**

Null tests in Java

```
if (x != null && y != null) {
    x.doSomething();
    y.doSomethingElse();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @Gorcyn but yes, it is also a string
private String spnOptionSelectedTypes = null;

Comment: Edited to answer to your own edition

Comment: hi @Gorcyn I copy the code wrong, it was with && not ||